# Protractor + double click an element?

Tags: protractor

I want to double an element in protractor; i am using as below but it is not doing a double click, instead a single click.

```
browser.actions().doubleClick(element(by.xpath("//*[@id='optionsTaggingList']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]")).getAttribute(1)).perform()
```

Is there something  am i missing?

Comment: First of all please use the correct code markup, makes it easier to read. Secondly, `. getAttribute()` doesn't return an ElementFinder, but a a result value of the attribute you are requesting. You can't click on that.

Comment: Never Use `//*[@id='optionsTaggingList']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]` such xpath

Comment: @KishanPatel right....is this better?  element(by.xpath("//*[@id='optionsTaggingList']//td[1]"))

Comment: @wswebcreation ok right. i have updated the xpath ("//*[@id='optionsTaggingList']//td[1]")). i have removed .getattribute and then also once single click happened.

Comment: You can still improve. avoid using `/`

Comment: `doubleclick()` is having issue and it is logged in `github`

Comment: ok right..thanks kishan

Answer (score 2):

just use:

```
browser.actions().doubleClick(element(by.xpath("//*[@id='optionsTaggingList']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]"))).perform();
```

But you should use a more simple selector, not so long.

Comment: ok right @bob...is this look better? var ele = element(by.xpath("//*[@id='optionsTaggingList']//td[1]"))

        browser.actions().doubleClick(ele).perform(); but still it is performing single click only.

Comment: try to click the element first and then double click it. browser.actions().click(ele).doubleClick(ele).perform();

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked:

```
var ele = element(by.xpath("//*[@id='optionsTaggingList']//td[1]"))   
browser.actions().click(ele).click(ele).perform();
```

Comment: which webdriver and which version are you using? It could be a problem in the webdriver and protractor itself why the `doubleClick()` isn't working

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple ways to double click an element, I finally came up with a solution:

```
async performDoubleClick(elemetToBeClicked: ElementFinder) {
            await browser.actions().mouseMove(elemetToBeClicked).mouseMove(elemetToBeClicked)
                .mouseUp().mouseDown().click().mouseDown().mouseUp().click().doubleClick().perform();
            return;
        }
```

You can also check if the following works for you:

```
async performDoubleClick(elemetToBeClicked: ElementFinder) {
        await browser.actions().mouseMove(elemetToBeClicked).mouseMove(elemetToBeClicked).doubleClick().perform();
    }
```

Other events are required to be stringed together because when you double click then these events are also being called in the same sequence. You can verify it from https://unixpapa.com/js/testmouse.html or any other mouse event checker.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above ,It didnot help, Try this

Please use sleep(1000)
  await browser.actions().click(ele.getWebElement()).perform();
               await browser.actions().mouseMove(ele).mouseMove(ele).doubleClick().perform();